# BASH- trouble pinging from text file lines

Tags: bash, text-files, ping

Have a text file w/ around 3 million URL's of sites I want to block.
Trying to ping them one by one (yes, I know it is going to take some time).
Have a script (yes, I am a bit slow in BASH) which reads the lines one at a time from text file.
Obviously cannot print text file here.  Text file was created >> w/ Python some time ago.
Problem is that ping returns "unknown host" w/ every entry.  If I make a smaller file by hand using the same entries the script works.  I thought it may be a white space or end of line issue so tried addressing that in script.  What could the issue possibly be?

```
  #!/bin/bash
  while read line
  do
    li=$(echo $line|tr -d '\n')
    li2=$(echo $li|tr -d ' ')
    if [ ${#line} -lt 2 ]
    then
      continue
    fi
    ping -c 2 -- $li2>>/dev/null
    if [ $? -gt 0 ]
    then 
       echo 'bad'
    else
       echo 'good'
    fi
    done<'temp_file.txt'
```

Comment: standard debugging tip; change the shebang to include `-x` and look at the output... see [bashdebugtips](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) Please update question with snippet from url-list

Comment: you could also add `set -x` before the `while`

Comment: Please post a small sample of what the file looks like.  The host names can be just example.com as long as we can see how you have formatted it.  In particular, `tr -d ' '` looks like you have something in the file which is slightly out of the ordinary.  ... Also, +1 to "don't use ping for this" as in the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

Does the file contains URLs or hostnames ?

If it contains URLs you must extract the hostname from URLs before pinging:

```
hostname=$(echo "$li2"|cut -d/ -f3);
ping -c 2 -- "$hostname"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ping is used to ping hosts. If you have URLs of websites, then it will not work. Check that you have hosts in your file , example `www.google.com` or an IP address and not actual full website urls. If you want to check actual URLs, use a tool like `wget` and another tool like `grep/awk` to grab for errors like 404 or others. Last but not least, people who are security conscious will sometimes block pinging from the outside, so take note.

Comment: +1. Add to this server load balancing, no reason to expect a load balanced IP address to reply to pings.

Answer (score 0):

C heck if the file contains windows-style `\r\n` line endings: `head file | od -c`

If so, to fix it: `dos2unix filename filename`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `ping` for this. It can easily be blocked, and it's not the best way to check for either ip addresses or if a server presents web pages.

If you just want to find the corresponding IP, use `host`:

```
$ host www.google.com
www.google.com is an alias for www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.149.106
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.149.147
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.149.99
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.149.103
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.149.104
www.l.google.com has address 209.85.149.105
```

As you see, you get all the IPs registered to a host. (Note that this requires you to parse the hostname from your urls!)

If you want to see if a URL points at a web server, use `wget`:

```
wget --spider $url
```

The `--spider` flag makes `wget` not save the page, just check that it exists. You could look at the return code, or add the `-S` flag (which prints the HTTP headers returned)